# Hide WPF ComboBox without visible items in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

iIs there a pure XAML way to hide ComboBox when all its items are collapsed?

For example, I have a combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsAlive, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Expected behavior: If all persons are dead, combobox is not visible, but if at least single person is alive, combobox is visible (and show only alive persons)

I already implemented this behaviour in code using the `CollectionViewSource`, `Filter` and count of elements in `CollectionViewSource.View` after filter is applied, but I prefer to achieve that without code behing only in XAML.

**EDIT:**
I need a universal solution usable in all ComboBoxes as part of style, not assigned with the Person type or IsAlive property... so a solution should depends only on visibility property of contained items

Comment: Why not do the same thing as you are already doing for the individual items? I.e. bind the `ComboBox.Visibility` property to the `Persons` property, and use a converter to scan the collection and return `Visibility.Visible` if any item has `IsAlive` set to `true`, and `Visibility.Collapsed` otherwise. Since you're clearly already aware of this approach, it would be helpful if you would explain in your question why that doesn't work for this particular goal. Even better, provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows all this.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Because I need a universal solution usable in all CheckBoxes as part of style, not assigned with the Person type or IsAlive property... so a solution should depends only on visibility property of contained items

Comment: CheckBoxes or ComboBoxes?

Comment: I don't think you can do "pure XAML". At some point, some code-behind needs to translate the state of a collection to the visibility. That said, you can bind to the `ItemsSource` collection, and then in your converter use `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem()` to retrieve the visual container representing your data item. From that, you can check its visibility, rather than having to write model-specific code.

Comment: Is there a reason your View Model has to return all persons both living and dead?  If instead you bind to "LivingPersons" then your visibility issue is made simple by converting the HasItems property of the ComboBox class to a Visibility property. Also why are you using what appears to be your hand rolled BoolToVis converter and not the BooleanToVisibilityConverter class available in System.Windows.Controls?

Comment: You might want to create an attached property (i.e. HideOnEmpty)  to a combo box to make it reusable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this attached property to hide the combobox if the items property is either null, empty or all of the items inside is not visible (Visibility.Collapsed)

Create a new class ComboBoxExt (or whatever you want to call it) then add an attached property. 
(TIP: You can type in "propa" in visual studio then tab twice, it will give you a template for attached property)

```
public class ComboBoxExt
  {
    public static bool GetHideOnEmpty(DependencyObject obj)
    {
      return (bool)obj.GetValue(HideOnEmptyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHideOnEmpty(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
      obj.SetValue(HideOnEmptyProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HideOnEmptyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HideOnEmpty", typeof(bool), typeof(ComboBoxExt), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, HideOnEmptyChanged));

    private static void HideOnEmptyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var cbox = d as ComboBox;

      if (cbox == null)
        return;

      HideComboBox(cbox, (bool)e.NewValue);
    }
    //This is where we check if all the items are not visible
    static void HideComboBox(ComboBox cbox, bool val)
    {
      //First, we have to know if the HideOnEmpty property is set to true. 
      if (val)
      {
        //Check if the combobox is either null or empty
        if (cbox.Items == null || cbox.Items.Count < 1)
          cbox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Hide the combobox
        else
        {
          bool hide = true;
          //Check if all the items are not visible.  
          foreach (ComboBoxItem i in cbox.Items)
          {
            if (i.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
              hide = false;
              break;
            }
          }

          //If one or more items above is visible we won't hide the combobox.
          if (!hide)
            cbox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          else
            cbox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now you can reuse the attached property in every combobox you want. You just have to set HideOnEmpty to true.

```
<ComboBox local:ComboBoxExt.HideOnEmpty="True"/>
```

With this solution you won't be having a code behind and you can reuse the attached property, HideOnEmpty, on every comboboxes you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of 'filtering' the combobox items is incorrect and highly non-performant[1]. You should use a `CollectionView`/`CollectionViewSource` to filter the `Persons` collection and not assign visibility within the `ItemContainerStyle`. Once this is achieved, you can use a simple binding and converter in the `ComboBox.Visibility` property using the bound `CollectionView.IsEmpty` property.

[1] Regarding performance: Currently a container will be created for every `Person` object before the Visibility binding will be evaluated.